# Python IRC bot question

Tags: python, irc, bots

I want to make a bot that will allow me to define functions from irc and treat my bot like a Python interpreter too.

For example, I want to make a bot that can do something like the following:

```
<mynick> py print "test"
<bot> test
<mynick> define hi(): print "hi"
<mynick> hi()
<bot> hi
```

MY QUESTION IS HOW TO DO THIS

Comment: I hope it's sandboxed or only allows **you** to run Python code. (don't do this:) `py __import__("subprocess").call(['rm -rf /'])`

Comment: That's great. What's your question?

Comment: Obviously I'm wondering how to do this.

Comment: Maybe one of the many existing bots which does exactly this would serve as an example of what is necessary.  Here's a random hit I found with google, http://inamidst.com/phenny/

Comment: I am doing this to learn so I'd rather make my own bot.

Comment: @Jean-Paul What??? Did you use a search engine to actually search for an answer? How did you come with a brilliant idea like that?

Comment: @gary you're not doing it, you are asking how to do it. I don't see it any different from looking at how others are made.

Comment: What are you talking about?  I am aware that their exist a plethora of Python IRC bots and frameworks, I am wondering how to be able to do this particular thing that no bot that I have seen does.  Phenny can do simple things like evaluate expressions, but it cannot define functions and store them from IRC itself.

Comment: How to do it? What have you tried any why didn't that work?

Comment: You people are useless.  Shouldn't of even come here.  Blind leading the blind.

Comment: > Phenny can do simple things like evaluate expressions, but it cannot define functions and store them from IRC itself - That's getting closer to the question you should be asking then.  Not "MY QUESTION IS HOW TO DO THIS" but "How do I accept Python source a line at a time, accepting multi-line statements and preserving the results for later use?"

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about security (and if this is a personal project then that's a valid assumption), then Python has several functions (`compile`, `exec`, `eval`) that can help here. Note that there are differences between Python 2 and Python 3, but the following example works for both:

```
>>> s = "print('hello world')"
>>> code = compile(s, "<string>", "exec")
>>> exec(code)
hello world
```

If you're going to let other people use this bot, you will want to pay very careful attention to the functions you let people call. For example, most things in the `os` module have potential to do undesirable things in an irc bot context.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [skybot](https://github.com/rmmh/skybot/), which has functionality close to what you want.

```
<rmmh> .py print "hello %03d, %s" % (5, "blah")
<skybot> Scaevolus: hello 005, blah
```

The Python interpreter runs on GAE and is a clone of http://shell.appspot.com/ modified to not store state, to prevent people from breaking the bot.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook your code into this: http://tumbolia.appspot.com/py/

```
import urllib, urllib2
uri = 'http://tumbolia.appspot.com/py/'
response = urllib2.urlopen(uri + urllib.quote("print 'hello world!'")).read()
print response
```

The nice thing about this solution is that you don't have to worry about the code being executed on your server. This is how the IRC bot phenny executes python code for the '.py' command.