# Python IRC bot help

Tags: python, linux, function, irc, bots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python IRC bot question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520918/python-irc-bot-question)

How do I implement functionality into an existing Python IRC bot framework that ill accept Python source a line at a time, accepting multi-line statements and preserving the results for later use?  Like, if I want to define a function from my IRC window and then be able to call that function later as well as treat my bot as a Python interpreter, how is that possible?  I have seen someone do it before, but they wouldn't give me the source code.

My bot will run on a Linux VPS.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval), as it runs strings as Python code:

```
eval('print 3 + 1') # Outputs: 4
```

You can use this function to evaluate strings as Python code (in your case lines of IRC chat). Be *very* careful with this, as it allows arbitrary access to the Python interpreter, which can 'splode your computer if someone else gets hold of this thing.

Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're *trying* to achieve with this?

Comment: I am trying to make a bot for IRC that I can just experiment with since I am learning Python and I use IRC and it would be fun to see what I could do with it and it would be simple for me to be able to add functions right in the channel

Comment: What do you mean by *add functions*?

Comment: For example, I want to be able to do something like this in my IRC channel: `<mynick> define hi(): print "hi"
<mynick> hi()
<bot> hi`

Comment: `eval()` does that, but I'm not sure how you'll intercept `print` statements. That would be a simpler (and better imo) question to ask.